# Edit Rich Embed with local image

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Quick question: when I do

```js
const embed0 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("test1")
  
message.channel.send({embed: embed0}).then(msg => {
const attachment = new Discord
                      .MessageAttachment('./testimg.jpg', 'testimg.jpg');
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle('test')
     .attachFiles([attachment])
     .setImage('attachment://testimg.jpg');

msg.edit({files: ['./testimg.jpg'], embed: embed});
})
```

the Embed title updates but not the image. If I send the new embed as its own embed, it works. Furthermore, if I do a remote url, it also edits correctly. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You just can't edit files of a message. This is sad, but Discord hasn't added this feature yet. You can upvote to request the feature [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360041728292-Edit-sent-files).